# Is my Nikon D3100 a better camera than my friend's D300?

Tags: nikon-d3100, technology-generations, nikon-d300

Within the Nikon D range of cameras, which would you say is a better camera? The Nikon D300 or the Nikon D3100?

I am new to photography, and have the D3100 and a friend of mine has the D300 and she's big into photography. I don't know which is a better camera, mine or hers.

Comment: @mattdm, thanks for the update to remove the `comparison` tag, but the tag itself doesn't explain itself.

Comment: Many tags don't explain themselves. I've gone ahead and removed that one from all questions where it exists; there was really only one where it might have been useful and that was borderline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're different generations and different 'levels'.  Your friend's is a pro level and the D3100 is an entry level.  Your's may carry a slight edge in resolution and high ISO, but in every other way thats important, the D300 is almost certainly better.

Comment: Thank you for that. I thought that the D300 would be more of a pro's camera, but wasn't sure. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean better? It's rather subjective. If you want to compare the price: D300 is more expensive.

[Here](http://snapsort.com/compare/Nikon_D300-vs-Nikon_D3100) you can compare the two cameras.

Comment: Thank you @asalamon74, by looking at that site, it looks likes the D300 has more features. Thanks for that.